# my error/misunderstanding or a bug in this Couchbase N1QL tutorial

Tags: couchbase, sql++

I am looking at a N1QL tutorial [here](http://query.pub.couchbase.com/tutorial/#13):

Why does this query

```
SELECT fname, email, children
    FROM tutorial 
        WHERE LENGTH(children) > 0
```

return an empty array?

```
{
  "resultset": []
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because there is no "LENGTH" array function in N1QL (see [Array Functions](http://docs.couchbase.com/prebuilt/n1ql/n1ql-dp3/#array-functions.html)). Perhaps its an example error in the tutorial. Use ARRAY_LENGTH instead. e.g.

```
SELECT fname, email, children
    FROM tutorial 
    where ARRAY_LENGTH(children) > 0
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a LENGTH function in N1QL but it should only be used on strings. For Arrays use ARRAY_LENGTH, for objects(maps) use OBJECT_LENGTH. If you are not sure of the type then POLY_LENGTH can be used on any datatype.

Answer (score 1):

There is an updated list of functions that are now supported. 
http://docs.couchbase.com/prebuilt/n1ql/n1ql-dp4/N1QLRef-DP4.pdf